# Using vlc command line for capture device frin a network URL

Tags: vlc

I'm trying to capture a video using vlc.
The procedure is standard using the GUI :
enter the url e.g `http://some_site_some_video.mp4/playlist.m3u8` in the network protocol capture device tool (`ctrl+n`) in the next screen enter the path so save the file and that's it.
Tried using VLC docs, and the closest command I found was `vlc -I dummy -vvv input_stream --sout` 
but

```
vlc -I dummy -vvv http://some_site_some_video.mp4/playlist.m3u8 --sout home/me/videos
```

Didn't work.
Is it the right command to use?

Comment: Redo what you do in the VLC app but enable debug logs before.

Comment: you mean open messages window and set verbosity to 2? if so, I don't see a way of extracting a command out of the messages (most are "Trying to run lua script XXX")